# Using Composer to Install My Own Application

Tags: php, json, composer-php

Is there a way to get composer to download my application into my root folder?

I'd like users to be able to run the following in their docroot:

```
composer require name/package
```

And have that download all my application files to the docroot, then install dependencies into vendor via the composer.json file.

```
composer install
```

Is this even possible?

I thought I could use the `repositories` directive in the `composer.json` but it still installs all my files into `vendor`

My composer.json looks like so:

```
{
    "name": "username/package",
    "description": "My App Description",
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.5.0",
        "raven/raven": "0.11.0",
        "filp/whoops": "~1.0",
        "robmorgan/phinx": "*",
        "swiftmailer/swiftmailer": "@stable"
    },
    "minimum-stability": "dev"
}
```

Any way to add my package and have it install where I want?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok I found the answer: `create-project`

```
composer create-project name/package public_html --stability="dev"
```

This will create the public_html directory and download all the dependencies.

Perfect.

Answer (score -2):

Move your `composer.json` at the root of your package. Then, simply create a git repository ensuring the `composer.json` is in the root, and push it to a service such as github.

Visit: https://packagist.org/packages/submit (sign in required) and paste your git url in the `Repository URL` field.

Please ensure that you follow the [Composer  naming conventions](https://packagist.org/about)

Comment: I already have that.  When requiring the package `composer require name/package` it installs everything into a single `vendors` directory.